# jekyll "back" button from blog post

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a `blog/index.html` file with a list of blog posts and excerpts. once i click on a blog post, it opens up in a new page in its entirety.
I would like to place a "back" button at the end of each post that should go back at the last page you visited.

is there a liquid tag to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no liquid tag that you can use. However, you have a choice of placing a link with static destination link like this:

`<a href="/blog">Back</a>`

Or you can use javascript to take user to the previously visited page

`<a onclick="window.history.back()">Back</a>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go back to the site root (edit, thanks [coatless](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1345455/coatless)). This works.

With markdown:

```
[Back]({{ site.url }}/)
```

With HTML:

```
<a href='{{site.url}}/'>Back</a>
```

Also check out: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination/

Comment: This goes back to the root of the blog page. Not to the previous page the user was on.